# Is there a way to make emission shader not looking flat?

Tags: emission

[image]

Glow is justice, but-but emission shader looks flat! I believe we can do a greater justice by making it not looking flat. Is there a way to make emission not look flat? I wonder? ><

Answer (score 6):

As Jachym says, you can get a good result with the *Principled BSDF* (choose a color for *Emission*, a *Strength* value will be implemented in the next Blender):

[image]

You could also mix the *Emission* with a *Diffuse*, but it looks like it needs some subtle tweakings to keep the bloom and prevent the color to be burnt:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey :). You could also use the Emission inside Principled BSDF. Then you can easily control roughness and specularity.

Comment: oh you're right, I couldn't get the same result with the Principled BSDF, I don't know why